# Is WPF's FlowDocument content user-editable?

Tags: wpf, flowdocument

I understand and have read about using WPF's FlowDocument to create an XML style document on screen, but is the content presented editable by the user, or is it read only? And, if so, how is this done?

My question mostly centres around the use of the listitem control because it would be nice to be able to edit the order of the list items presented for use in my program, rather than me having to create my own custom control(s).

Regards.

Answer (score 6):

`FlowDocuments` as objects are editable, if they can be edited in the UI depends on the controls that use them. If you use them in a `Page` they are not, if you use them in a `RichTextBox` they are.

Comment: Can you then control which items are editable? or toggle them from editable to readonly viabackground code?

Comment: @LucyViolet: I do not know if this is possible. I would recommend looking through the properties of the relevant classes.